# 1d heat equation in maple

Tags: for-loop, maple

I am solving 1d heat equation with neumman boundary conditions by finite difference method on maple but my code is not working please can anyone of you suggest me some better code for this equation on maple..

> restart;
>   with(LinearAlgebra);
>   FX := 1;
>   FT := 0.5e-1;
>   M := 5;
>   N := 5;
>   M1 := M-1;
>   H := FX/M;
>   K := FT/N; c := 1;
>   r := c^2*K/H^2;
>
> ## loop for initial condition;
>
> for i to M1 do V[i, 0] := cos(Pi*i*H) end do;
>
> ## loop for boundary condition;
>
> for j to N do V[-1, j] := V[1, j] end do;
>   for j to N do V[M+1, j] := V[M-1, j] end do;
>
> ## loop for discretized equation;
>
> for j from 0 to N-1 do for i to M-1 do V[i, j+1] := (1-2*r)*V[i, j]+r*V[i-1, j]+r*V[i+1, j] end do end do;

please friends let me know why my last loop is not executing.

Answer (score 1):

Very much a subtlety of Maple.  The loop is executing - it just isn't printing the results.  Every level of statement nesting adds one to the "printlevel" of the statement.  Entering a procedure adds 5 to the printlevel of the containing procedure.  The interactive session is level 0.   The results of statements are only printed if their printlevel is less than or equal to the global variable printlevel which defaults to one.  To see your loop execute, try

```
printlevel := 4;
```

Which prints up to 4 levels of nesting but not into any procedure calls.  See ?printlevel for the full details.

On a side note, you may want to evalf the cos calls to ensure you get floating point values.